# Image comparison of HD and SD images using Java

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, edge-detection

I have a database containing both the SD and HD version of same set of images. Problem is that their names are different from each other.

For example an image of a flower in SD has a name `greatflower.png` and the same flower has HD version with the name `bestflower.png`

The challenge is to find a similarity between them. I have tried resizing the images to the same width and height and then pixel by pixel comparing them but the results are not accurate. I just want to have an answer in terms of yes or no after the algorithm is done performing comparison between a pair of images.

My question is which library of java or algorithm will perform a perfect image similarity analysis between an HD and SD version of the image ?

Thanking you all in anticipation :)

Comment: Examining every pixel in a bitmap in Java could be horribly slow if you have many candidates.  Check the aspect ratios are similar. I would then extract 100 points from both images (from an equally spaced 10x10 grid over each image) and compare them. Say two points are "the same" if the RGB values are each within 10%. If 90% of the points are "the same", then the images are deemed to be the same. This is far from foolproof, but computationally only requires 100 lookups per image. It will probably work fine. Change the 10x10 to some other grid size to trade-off performance against sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks a million sir.Your suggestion did the work in my case :)

Answer (score 1):

I would as a first step create color histograms of all images (for a reduced color-depth).
Than you can use the histogram similarity to find candidates of same images.

In a second step I would resize both images to the same (quite small) size and than make a pixel by pixel comparison with little tolerance related to the colors. If more than 90% of the pixels are very similar, I would classify the images as being the same.